# Local integration test fails if a PowerMock test runs before

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, powermock

I've written a local integration test for HBase that runs on Windows, using `HBaseTestingUtility` to set up a local instance of HBase:

```
public class HBaseTestServer extends ExternalResource {
    private HBaseTestingUtility hbaseUtility;

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("test.build.data.basedirectory", "C:/Temp/hbase");
        this.hbaseUtility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
        this.hbaseUtility.startMiniCluster();
   }
   ...
```

It works fine if I run the integration test class by itself. However, this class runs after another test class, which uses PowerMock to mock HBase:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({HBaseAdapter.class, Connection.class, ConnectionFactory.class})
public class HBaseAdapterTest {
    ...
```

If I run all tests on my project, the PowerMock `HBaseAdapterTest` runs first, and my integration test fails with the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:977)
```

What's going on here? I presume I need to erase all PowerMock mocks before my integration test runs, but I can't find anything useful online.

For anyone curious about dependencies:

```
compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.8.1'
compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.1.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.7.0'
```

Comment: As an aside, I can get everything to work if I change my package structure so that the integration test runs first, but I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't rely on the tests running in alphabetical order.

Comment: since powermock does use bytecode-manipulation it's probably best to separate your unit-tests (using mocking) and integration-tests by using different jvm-instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Tom's comment, running tests in separate instances has solved my problem. In `build.gradle` I added:

```
test {
    forkEvery 1
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to accept other answers; I suspect there are better solutions.